# .NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ could not be loaded when trying to download SSMS Express 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm receiving the following error upon installation of [SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) :

[image: Installation Problem]

I do have this version installed.  I've been trying to figure this out for hours but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

could you check your installation logs for a bit more information on what went wrong? Logs are available at: **'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt'** by default for SQL Server 2014.

Also, have you tried the SQL Server 2016 Express edition? It was just released: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679

**Disclaimer: I work on the SQL Server tools team at Microsoft**